# GMAIL API NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, gmail-api, cheerio

I have set up a gmail api service to query my email. My connection is established and I am just looking to download a file attachment. I am having no trouble finding the file. The road block I have is being able to download the file into my local drive so that I can perform some data cleaning with js. My code is below. The fileAttachment.value return the name of the file but I want to download the content of the .htm document. I appreciate any help.

```
//This api call will fetch the mailbody.
      this.gmail.users.messages.get({
            'userId': this.me,
            'id': msgId
        }, (err, res) => {
            if(!err){
                // console.log(res.data.payload)
                
                // var htmlBody = base64.decode(body.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'));
                // var mailparser = new Mailparser();
                let body = res.data.payload.headers;

                let fileAttachment = body.find(r => r.name === 'Content-Disposition')

                console.log(fileAttachment.value)

                
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Update: Working Solution.

```
    getMail(msgId, attachmentId, size,callback){
        //This api call will fetch the mailbody.
        this.gmail.users.messages.get({
            'userId': this.me,
            'id': msgId,
            'attachmentId': attachmentId,
            'size':size
        }, (err, res) => {
            if(!err){
                // console.log(res.data.payload)

                let getCurrentDate = new Date();

                getCurrentDate = getCurrentDate.setDate(getCurrentDate.getDate()-1); 

                getCurrentDate = new Date(getCurrentDate);

                console.log(getCurrentDate)
                
                msgId = res.data.id;
                
                attachmentId = res.data.payload.body.attachmentId;

                size = res.data.payload.body.size; 
                

                this.gmail.users.messages.attachments.get({
                    "userId": this.me,
                    "messageId": msgId,
                    "id": attachmentId
                }).then(res => {

                    const buff = Buffer.from(res.data.data, 'base64');

                    fs.writeFileSync('./data/cooler-report.htm', buff)

                    console.log(`Cooler Report File for ${getCurrentDate} created!`)

                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(`Error converting file ${error}`)
                })
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).